# whois-json whois npm package lib doesn't work in bun

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-package, bun

so I have this simple file `whois.js`:

[image: code snipet and log]

It's pretty simple, in node it works and in bun just runs forever.
In the image it shows the return in node and the time it took until I forced cancelled the process in bun.

I don't really know what else to put in the question, if you need any more information please comment and I'll provide.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that export?

Comment: care to elaborate on your real goal instead of the code? Perhaps a simple bash script could solve your real problem.

Comment: I have a rest api that I need to lookup the domain of a website do get its document number (CNPJ in brazil) and with that I use government APIs to get the company info on its owners and another things. All this must be a function because I use it in an endpoint that is a search engine for brazilian companies, I also get linkedin and google data. My api runs with bun.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you install express types `npm install @types/express` and in your .ts file `import {Application} from 'express'`

Your code would look like this:

```
import { Application } from "express";
import userController from "./userController.js"
import getController from "./getController.js"
import productController from "./productController.js"

const exportArr = [userController, getController, productController]

export default (app: Application) => {
    exportArr.forEach(controller => controller(app))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gave it a try and everything works as expected on Linux at least. Are you sure it is not something to do with some config on your system or some issues with bun installation?

```bash
elvis@ubuntu:~/test$ bun run index.ts 
{
  "2023_11_06T20": "23:15-03:00 - IP: 2.131.246.11",
  domain: "virtu.com.br",
  owner: "Virtu Assessoria Empresarial ltda",
  ownerid: "67.643.882/0001-84",
  responsible: "Marcio Antonio Rosconi",
  country: "BR BR BR",
  ownerC: "TRA56",
  techC: "MAARO1014",
  nserver: "ns1.locaweb.com.br ns2.locaweb.com.br ns3.locaweb.com.br",
  nsstat: "20231106 AA 20231106 AA 20231106 AA",
  nslastaa: "20231106 20231106 20231106",
  created: "20051017 #2425251 20041117 20191107",
  changed: "20221018 20230920 20201005",
  expires: "20321017",
  status: "published",
  nicHdlBr: "TRA56 MAARO1014",
  person: "Talles Rodrigues Alves marcio antonio rosconi",
  eMail: "talles@cpc.com.br marcio.rosconi@virtu.com.br",
  ofQueriesAre: "domain (.br), registrant (tax ID), ticket,"
}
```

Comment: I dont know, installed bun through brew, pretty standard, I use mac. Makes sense, I rewrote the lib in js and still wasn't working. Might be my config

Comment: the extension in my example is `ts` from using `bun init`, otherwise it is the same code you posted

Comment: I discovered that it breaks during the build process. While it functions properly with Bun.js, it encounters a syntax issue that I believe Bun.js doesn't support when attempting to build. Unfortunately, there's nothing I can do to resolve this issue. I decided to fork the repository and implement a fix for my project. I did consider opening a pull request, but the repository's owner hasn't made any changes in the past three years. I thought it would be helpful to document this here.

Comment: damn, sounds like a bit of a rabbit whole. glad you solved it